# CSS Box Shadow Around Entire Div In IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I cannot get box-shadow to create a shadow around the entire perimeter of a div. The following works in FireFox, however not in IE 11.

I have tried the following: [Internet Explorer - CSS Shadow All Around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840944/internet-explorer-css-shadow-all-around)

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6TL/) for the problem.
CSS:

```
 .addAccountPanel
 {
    width:250px; 
    height:200px; 
    margin:auto; 
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
    position:relative; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #004C7E;
 }
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="addAccountPanel"> </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's not something else conflicting with this? It works for me even as far back as IE9.

Comment: The shadow does not seem as vibrant. You can barely see it on the top and bottom of the div

Comment: That might just be on account of the different rendering methods used across browsers. You can make it more "vibrant" (read: thicker) by changing your value of `4px` to something like `10px` for `box-shadow:` and add a `-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #004C7E;` line.

Comment: your fiddle works in my IE11

Comment: I am going with @TylerH's suggestion and specifying thickness for specific browsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a fourth parameter in the box-shadow that lets you increase the size of the shadow, and makes it more visible

```
.addAccountPanel
    {
        width:250px; 
        height:200px; 
        margin:auto; 
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .2); 
        position:relative; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 2px #004C7E;
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb6TL/11/)

Comment: Thanks this works! If you combine it with TylerH's comment above about specifying for browsers I can give you the answer.